# \addcontentsline link isn't taking me to correct page

Tags: table-of-contents, links, preamble

Here's the code:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\let\d=\pgfcalendarshorthand
\newcommand\formatdate[2]{\pgfcalendar{cal}{#1}{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\firstdate{2022-01-01}
\newcommand\lastdate{2022-01-30}

\newcommand\grayrule{{\color{gray} \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}}}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Days}

\begin{document}
  % Table of Contents
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
  
  \pgfcalendar{cal}{\firstdate}{\lastdate}{
    % Set a couple of variables
    \def\formatteddate{\d{y}0/\d{m}0/\d{d}0} % EXM: 2022/06/10
    \def\todayformatted{\d{y}0-\d{m}0-\d{d}0} % EXM: 2022-06-10

    \def\firstdayofyear{2022-01-01} % EXM: 2022-01-01

    \def\firstdayofmonth{\d{y}0-\d{m}0-01} % EXM: 2022-08-01
    \def\monthgoalsformat{./\d{y}0/\d{m}0/goals.tex} % EXM: 2022/01/goals.tex

    % Check if it's the first day of the year
    \pgfcalendarifdate{\todayformatted}{equals=\firstdayofyear}{
      % Add the year to the table of contents
      \noindent{\Huge \d{y}0}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\d{y}0}%
      \newline
      \newline
    }{}

    \ifdate{equals=\firstdayofmonth}{
      % Add the month to the table of contents
      % \section*{\d{m}t}
      \noindent{\LARGE \d{m}t}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\d{m}t}
      \newline
      \newline
      % Add the goals to the table of contents
      \noindent{\Large Goals for \d{m}t}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Goals for \textbf{\d{m}t}}
    }{}
    
    \noindent{\Large \d{m}t \d{d}- \d{y}-}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\d{m}t \d{d}0. \d{y}0}
    \newpage
  }
\end{document}
```

The links on the table of contents are clickable, but they don't bring me to the correct page number. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to insert \phantomsection before each line containing a date, e.g. `\phantomsection\noindent{\Large Goals for \d{m}t}%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Celdor pointed out, I need to use `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline`.

Here's how the final code looks like with the correction

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\let\d=\pgfcalendarshorthand
\newcommand\formatdate[2]{\pgfcalendar{cal}{#1}{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\firstdate{2022-01-01}
\newcommand\lastdate{2022-01-30}

\newcommand\grayrule{{\color{gray} \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}}}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Days}

\begin{document}
  % Table of Contents
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
  
  \pgfcalendar{cal}{\firstdate}{\lastdate}{
    % Set a couple of variables
    \def\formatteddate{\d{y}0/\d{m}0/\d{d}0} % EXM: 2022/06/10
    \def\todayformatted{\d{y}0-\d{m}0-\d{d}0} % EXM: 2022-06-10

    \def\firstdayofyear{2022-01-01} % EXM: 2022-01-01

    \def\firstdayofmonth{\d{y}0-\d{m}0-01} % EXM: 2022-08-01
    \def\monthgoalsformat{./\d{y}0/\d{m}0/goals.tex} % EXM: 2022/01/goals.tex

    % Check if it's the first day of the year
    \pgfcalendarifdate{\todayformatted}{equals=\firstdayofyear}{
      % Add the year to the table of contents
      \noindent{\Huge \d{y}0}
      \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\d{y}0}%
      \newline
      \newline
    }{}

    \ifdate{equals=\firstdayofmonth}{
      % Add the month to the table of contents
      % \section*{\d{m}t}
      \noindent{\LARGE \d{m}t}
      \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\d{m}t}
      \newline
      \newline
      % Add the goals to the table of contents
      \noindent{\Large Goals for \d{m}t}
      \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Goals for \textbf{\d{m}t}}
    }{}
    
    \noindent{\Large \d{m}t \d{d}- \d{y}-}
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\d{m}t \d{d}0. \d{y}0}
    \newpage
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This should be a comment or edited into the question as an addendum.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I came across a similar issue today. The answer here _perfectly answered_ my situation. Using comments to answer questions is highly inappropriate on Stack Exchange, since "[comments are ephemeral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130990)". And editing the question with the answer would make the question obsolete.

Comment: You've taken care of the problem by adding substantive details, which weren't present when I commented,  Now it's a real answer.